# Async Task not executing

Tags: android, asynchronous, gps

New to this, but I can't see any problem. There's a checkbox in settings to start the Async task hence the if statement in onCreate. I just get a Java null error on the line where the task is executed.

Code

```
ProgressDialog progressDialog;
double longitude, latitude;
Location location;

private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters


private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute


protected LocationManager locationManager;

GPSLocation task = new GPSLocation();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_confirm_screen);
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Boolean locationCheck = sp.getBoolean("LOCATION", false);
  if(locationCheck){

        task.execute();
    }
   else
   {
    sendEmail();
    playSound();
   }

}

public double getLatitude()
{
    if (location != null)
    {
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    return latitude;
}

public double getLongitude()
{
    if (location !=  null)
    {
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }
    return longitude;
}

public class GPSLocation extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> implements LocationListener
{  
    boolean running =true;
            @Override
            protected void onPreExecute()
            {  
                super.onPreExecute(); 
                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(ConfirmScreen.this);
                progressDialog.setOnCancelListener(new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                      public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {
                          //getgps.cancel(true);  
                      }
                });

                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                            if (location != null) {
                                    latitude = location.getLatitude();
                                    longitude = location.getLongitude();  
                                    progressDialog.setCancelable(true);
                                    progressDialog.setMessage("Getting GPS Location...");
                                    progressDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
                                    progressDialog.setProgress(1);
                                    progressDialog.show();
                            }
                }

            } 

            @Override 
            protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
                super.onProgressUpdate(values);
                // Things to be done while execution of long running operation is in progress. For example updating ProgessDialog
             }

            @Override 
            protected void onPostExecute(Void result)
            {  
                    progressDialog.cancel(); 
                    sendEmail("GPS: ", Double.toString(longitude).trim(), Double.toString(latitude).trim());
                    playSound();
            }

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {  
                boolean isDataSubmitted = false;

                while(!isDataSubmitted)
                {  
                    if(longitude !=0 && latitude!=0)
                    { 
                        sendEmail(); //Send Email without co-ords
                        playSound();
                        isDataSubmitted = true;  
                    }  
                } 

                return null;    
            }

            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status,
                    Bundle extras) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            } 
 } 


public void backHome(View view) 
{
    Intent intent = new Intent (this, MainScreen.class);
    startActivity(intent);
}

// Method to start playing and looping a sound.

public void playSound()
{
    MediaPlayer clickSound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.warning);
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    Boolean soundCheck = sp.getBoolean("SOUND", false);
    if (soundCheck)
    {
        clickSound.start();
    }



}// method end

public void sendEmail()
{
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String nameValue = sp.getString("NAME", "failed to get name");
    String emailValue = sp.getString("EMAIL", "failed to get email");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailValue});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email sent from DON'T PANIC - A Chris O'Brien Project");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi there\n" + nameValue + " is in mortal danger. They didn't include co-ords as they assume you know where they are..\nKind Regards\nDon't Panic! \n\n\n");

    try
    {   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...."));
    } 
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){

        Toast.makeText(ConfirmScreen.this, "There are no email clients installed or set up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


public void sendEmail(String a, String b, String c)
{
    SharedPreferences sp = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
    String nameValue = sp.getString("NAME", "failed to get name");
    String emailValue = sp.getString("EMAIL", "failed to get email");
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("message/rfc822");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{emailValue});
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Email sent from DON'T PANIC - A Chris O'Brien Project");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hi there\n" + nameValue + " is in mortal danger. Please see the co-ords attached and run to their rescue!" +
            " If you don't see any co-ords, they didn't check the box and assume you know where they are.\nKind Regards\nDon't Panic! \n\n\n" + 
            a + b + c);

    try
    {   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Send mail...."));
    } 
    catch (android.content.ActivityNotFoundException ex){

        Toast.makeText(ConfirmScreen.this, "There are no email clients installed or set up", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}


@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_confirm_screen, menu);
    return true;
}






}
```

Debug Info

```
10-03 08:38:16.890: D/dalvikvm(27516): Late-enabling CheckJNI
10-03 08:38:16.990: I/dalvikvm(27516): Turning on JNI app bug workarounds for target SDK version 11...
10-03 08:38:17.030: E/Trace(27516): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-03 08:38:17.600: D/dalvikvm(27516): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 58K, 9% free 12206K/13315K, paused 105ms, total 111ms
10-03 08:38:17.610: I/dalvikvm-heap(27516): Grow heap (frag case) to 13.616MB for 784248-byte allocation
10-03 08:38:17.755: D/dalvikvm(27516): GC_CONCURRENT freed 1K, 8% free 12971K/14087K, paused 35ms+9ms, total 147ms
10-03 08:38:17.940: D/dalvikvm(27516): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 8% free 12971K/14087K, paused 32ms, total 32ms
10-03 08:38:17.985: I/dalvikvm-heap(27516): Grow heap (frag case) to 16.606MB for 3136944-byte allocation
10-03 08:38:18.025: D/dalvikvm(27516): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 7% free 16034K/17159K, paused 24ms+1ms, total 40ms
10-03 08:38:18.025: D/dalvikvm(27516): WAIT_FOR_CONCURRENT_GC blocked 4ms
10-03 08:39:44.110: E/SpannableStringBuilder(27516): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-03 08:39:44.110: E/SpannableStringBuilder(27516): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-03 08:39:45.145: E/SpannableStringBuilder(27516): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-03 08:39:45.145: E/SpannableStringBuilder(27516): SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
10-03 08:39:45.910: D/dalvikvm(27516): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 815K, 11% free 15718K/17543K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
10-03 08:39:45.910: I/dalvikvm-heap(27516): Grow heap (frag case) to 19.016MB for 2850872-byte allocation
10-03 08:39:45.925: D/dalvikvm(27516): GC_CONCURRENT freed 10K, 10% free 18492K/20359K, paused 1ms+1ms, total 12ms
10-03 08:39:45.955: D/dalvikvm(27516): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 0K, 10% free 18492K/20359K, paused 9ms, total 9ms
10-03 08:39:45.970: I/dalvikvm-heap(27516): Grow heap (frag case) to 29.882MB for 11403440-byte allocation
10-03 08:39:45.990: D/dalvikvm(27516): GC_CONCURRENT freed 0K, 7% free 29628K/31559K, paused 11ms+2ms, total 22ms
10-03 08:39:46.025: D/AndroidRuntime(27516): Shutting down VM
10-03 08:39:46.025: W/dalvikvm(27516): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41d77300)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{cs4084.panic.button/cs4084.panic.button.ConfirmScreen}: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2100)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2125)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:140)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1227)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4898)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1006)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:773)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at cs4084.panic.button.ConfirmScreen$GPSLocation.onPreExecute(ConfirmScreen.java:89)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.os.AsyncTask.executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.java:586)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.os.AsyncTask.execute(AsyncTask.java:534)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at cs4084.panic.button.ConfirmScreen.onCreate(ConfirmScreen.java:46)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5184)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1083)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2064)
10-03 08:39:46.035: E/AndroidRuntime(27516):    ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are getting a null pointer in onPreExecute method , so I guess locationManager is null , Try to initialize it as in onCreate() method.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) this
            .getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Hope this solves the null error problem.

Comment: I love you. :)

That sorted it, and it's now working, just the Progress Dialog isn't popping up, but I think that's down to me allowing it to use last known location. I'll work on that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you haven't instantiated your locationManager, use

```
 LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) this.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```

Comment: I love you too, but I saw his first :)

Answer (score 0):

You have not initialized `locationManager`
To fix this, in your onCreate method you can do something like:

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
```